AssemblyInfo and RazorAssemblyInfo files are not found in ASP.NET Core MVC project
I have been working on an ASP.NET Core MVC / C# project (Visual Studio 2022) for the last 2 months. I have a class in this project which contains some properties. The name of the property was in capital letters and it was working fine.
Today I changed the name of the property from capital letters to lowercase letters of that class - something like this:
public string STUD_NAME { get; set; }

to
public string stud_name { get; set; }   

After changing this, when I tried to run the app, it shows 2 errors:

The source file ~\ProjectName\obj\Debug\net6.0\AssemblyInfo.cs

and

~\ProjectName\obj\Debug\net6.0\RazorAssemblyInfo.cs - could not find these files.

But when I checked in the specific obj folder, these files are there.
But in the Solution Explorer, I couldn't find these 2 files anywhere including the Properties folder.
I removed this obj folder and recreated it by rebuilding the project. Still it shows the same errors. I cleaned the project and solution and rebuild it. Still shows same error.
Project properties as shown below:
     <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

     <PropertyGroup>    
       <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
       <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
       <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
       <RootNamespace>AMD_WEB</RootNamespace>
       <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Windows</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
       <DockerfileContext>.</DockerfileContext>
       <DockerComposeProjectPath>docker- 
           compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
       <UserSecretsId>9e0b460e-16bd-42c2-b790- 
           6fe2edd2b425</UserSecretsId>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
       <PackageReference Include="ClosedXML" Version="0.97.0" />
       <PackageReference            
  Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" 
  Version="6.0.11" />
      <PackageReference 
  Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" 
  Version="1.17.0" />
  <PackageReference 
   Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Kubernetes.Tools.Targets" 
   Version="1.1.0" />
   <PackageReference 
   Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" 
   Version="6.0.16" />
   <PackageReference Include="Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore" 
   Version="7.21.11" />
   <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs" 
   Version="7.0.3" />
 </ItemGroup>

</Project>

How to solve this issue?

Hi @KitKat, Step 1: Ensure that the new property name (stud_name) does not conflict with any other properties, fields, or methods in your class or in any of the base classes or interfaces it might be implementing.  Step 2:  Try to close the visual studio, manually delete the obj and bin folders from your project directory, reopen Visual Studio and rebuild the solution. This will force Visual Studio to regenerate all intermediate files.
